# Connect Azure SQL Database to .NET Project

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, azure, entity-framework

I have built a web api using dotnet and this is my first time using Azure (or any other cloud platform) to host web applications. I've used EntityFramework and MySQL database with to build my project.

I used `DbConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=hms;Uid='{root-user}';Pwd={pw};"` as the connection string of my SQL Database and now I'm wondering how can I connect it with the Azure SQL Database I have created. I added my IP address in firewall access in the Azure server and tried changing the connection string as `DbConnectionString = "Server=server.database.windows.net:1433;Database=hms;Uid='{root-user}';Pwd={pw};"` but it gives an error `An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseMySql' call.` when I'm trying to update the database after adding migrations.

I'd like to know what I have done wrong or what else I need to do in order to get this running. tyia.

Answer (score 0):

1. I have created an Azure SQL database with one table.
2. Table is having data as below[image]

3.Created Console application using C#.

4. Added Package  **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient**  to the Project.
5. Added following code in Program.cs file,

```
[Taking reference from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-dotnet-visual-studio?view=azuresql), I created a replica of the program.cs file as shown:
```

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
namespace sqltest
{
class Program
 {
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
try
 {
 SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder  = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
 builder.DataSource = "yourservername.database.windows.net";
 builder.UserID = "your_username";
 builder.Password = "your_password";
 builder.InitialCatalog = "your_database";
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
 {
 Console.WriteLine("\nQuery data example:");
Console.WriteLine("=========================================\n");

//String sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Persons";
String sql = "SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM dbo.Persons";
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
 connection.Open();
 using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
   while (reader.Read())
  {

    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",     reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));

           }
       }
    }
  }
}

catch (SqlException e)
{

Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

 }

Console.ReadLine();
   }
  }
}
```

6.Using above code, I am connecting to Azure SQL and retrieving data from database.

7. Run the application and getting data from Azure Sql data base as shown below,  [image]

**Reference links:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/azure-sql-database-add-connected-service?view=vs-2022